# Concatenate byte arrays without allocating

Tags: string, rust, byte

I would like to append a "marker" byte onto a byte slice to ensure it ends in a newline byte while parsing it.  Here's what I think it could look like:

```rs
fn parse(inp: &[u8]) {
    let workable_array = inp.basic_append(b'\n');
}
```

and when a byte is accessed beyond the length of the original input, it'll go onto the added byte. I'll be using the new array in a purely read-only context afterwards.

I'm aware of the [concat](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) method on slices, but this internally allocates an entirely new vector, which seems to be unnecessarily costly. Especially when the input string could potentially be very large.

Comment: It sounds like you want [`chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.chain) maybe?

Comment: @drewtato something in that spirit yes, but it'd need to work on byte arrays, not files

Comment: `Read` is for anything that produces bytes, whether it is files, byte slices, or something else.

Comment: You can use iterator's `chain()`. You cannot create an array, because you don't know the length at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for an operation that takes a `&[u8]` and returns another `&[u8]` that includes the newline byte, without reallocation, then the answer is that this is impossible. `&[u8]` is **always** contiguous memory, so the newline byte has to be physically located at the end of the slice, which can only be achieved through reallocation. Further, it isn't possible to do so with a `&[u8]` slice, because it is not `mut`able.

However, you can in fact achieve a similar effect with **iterators**. It will not allocate and simply provide another newline byte after all the other bytes got produced.

```rust
fn append_newline(data: impl Iterator<Item = u8>) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> {
    data.chain(std::iter::once(b'\n'))
}

fn main() {
    let s = "Hello";
    let s_iter_with_newline = append_newline(s.bytes());
    for b in s_iter_with_newline {
        println!("{:?}", b as char);
    }
}
```

```
'H'
'e'
'l'
'l'
'o'
'\n'
```

Of course this won't be compatible with functions that require a `&[u8]` as parameter.

---

Further remarks:

- It sounds like your input sometimes contains a newline and sometimes not. It is much easier to cut away the newline from the ones that have it than to add it to the ones that don't have it. Maybe change your parsing algorithm that so it requires the input without a newline?
- You are using `&[u8]` here for what sounds like string operations. Be aware that Rust characters are **not** `u8` - Rust strings are are instead a list of variably-sized UTF-8 characters. That's the reason why the `&str`/`String` types exist. Use those instead for string processing, as they can handle special characters, unlike `&[u8]`. Of course the `'\n'` problem you are having here still exists with `str`, it still isn't possible without reallocation.

Comment: Actually `char` is exactly 4 bytes long. It's only when strings are encoded, that they are made of variable-length utf8 codepoints.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Yes yes yes, you are of course right :) I reworded this section.

Comment: I don't think `chain` would work in my situation since I need to jump around the byte array and index arbitrary locations with backtracking. An iterator seems to be better for just reading text linearly. And the format I'm parsing just requires identifying ascii characters for patterns, and those are always 1 byte ;)

Comment: @aquabeam I guess then you need to reallocate + copy. I don't think there's a way around that. If you really need that newline character; I still think the best solution would be to avoid that requirement in the first place.

Comment: @aquabeam Well, of course you can build a wrapper that implements `Index` and behaves "as if" a newline was inserted, but this is going to be complicated. Reconsider if you don't just want to allocate.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Most API's don't want an `Index`, they all want a `&[u8]`, `&str` or their `AsRef`/`From`/`Into` versions. And I suspect that's the background, allthough I of course don't know for sure without context.